# Issue with Radio button checked in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, radio-button

I am working on a JSP page which is having multiple radio buttons with ids `ans1, ans2, ans3... etc`.. No of radio buttons varies depending upon on the response in previous page. User should select answer for all the radio buttons. i.e. user must select response for all the radio buttons ans1, ans2, ans3 ... etc. I have written a Javascript code for submit button click event as below for validation and to make sure user has responded to all the answers:

```
function beforeSubmit(){
    var obj = document.quizcreen;
    var qCount = obj.totQuesHidden.value;
    for (var i=1; i<=qCount; i++){
        if(document.getElementById("ans"+i).checked){
             // checked
        }else{
            alert("Please select ateleast one option");  // unchecked
            return false;
        }
    }
    obj.submit();
    return true;
}
```

For some reason above code is not working. The form should not be submitted if all the radio buttons are not selected. Please help, I know it's very simple and common issue, but I am unable to figure it out. Thanks in advance.

Also following is the form action:

```
<form name="quizcreen" id="quizcreen" method="post" action="QuizResult.jsp" onsubmit = "return beforeSubmit();">
```

Comment: The loop will encounter a checked radio, and then `return true`, what were you expecting to happen in that situation?

Comment: Ignore the return true in checked loop. I was trying something, that's why I put that there.

Comment: I removed the debugging code, and added the real code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found out a better way to handle my scenario, So I am sharing my code for your info:

```
function beforeSubmit() {
        var obj = document.quizcreen;
        var allChecked = true;
        $("input:radio").each(function() {
            var name = $(this).attr("name");
            if ($("input:radio[name=" + name + "]:checked").length == 0) {
                allChecked = false;
            }
        });
        if (!allChecked) {
            alert("Please answer all the questions."); // unchecked
            return false;
        }
        obj.submit();
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You have a `return true` statement in your loop. So when the first radiobutton is checked, it will not check the other ones.

```
function beforeSubmit(){
    var obj = document.quizcreen;
    var qCount = obj.totQuesHidden.value;
    var allChecked = true;
    for (var i=1; i<=qCount; i++){
        if(! document.getElementById("ans"+i).checked){
            allChecked = false;
        }
    }

    if(! allChecked){
        alert("Please select ateleast one option");  // unchecked
        return false
    }
    obj.submit();
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Actually it should work but still form is getting submitted, though I haven't selected all the radio buttons.

Comment: Below is the form action: <form name="quizcreen" id="quizcreen" method="post" action="QuizResult.jsp" onsubmit = "return beforeSubmit();"> if I remove onsubmit = "return beforeSubmit();" then form is getting submitted inspite of Javascript validation otherwise(if onsubmit = "return beforeSubmit();" is there) javascript function is called twice and alert is generated twice. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: @Sid works for me http://jsfiddle.net/zbxr6/4/ . The only thing I changed is the qCount. Maybe try to alert this value, check if it's filled?

Answer (score -1):

your problem is at least one to be checked.

do this stuff

```
function isRadioChecked() {
return ($('input[type=radio]:checked').size() > 0);
```

}

Comment: Did you see a jQuery tag somewhere..?

Comment: Oh! Sorry I said the shortest way.